# Change the background of a named <div> inside the 9th identically named <section>

Tags: css

I am trying to change the background from blue to red, but my code doesn't seem to target inside the 9th div. This is what I have tried so far (By the way in my real version of this script there is code in each  tab, but I am showing a basic example here to simplify things).

**CSS:**

```
.bg-layer {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.bg-layer .vc_section_wrapper:nth-child(9) {  
    background-color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color"></section>
    <section class="vc_section_wrapper has_bg_color">
    <div class="bg-layer"></div>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Since you have only one div why do u have to give nth-child? And question is so unclear. Do you want to change the blue to red or 9th section to red?

Comment: I left out what is in the other sections to demo to simplify the example, I should have explained that in the question.

Comment: So each section has a div with class name bg-layer inside it and you want to change the bg coor of last section div?

Comment: Check the answer below and this is not how you simplify the code by removing the main hint.

Comment: I had to clean up the code example to get it right, sorry all, really long night coding. The div tag is inside the section.

Comment: in that case you just have to add blank div with class name so it is easy to understand. Anyways leave it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup has exactly 9 sections....they why go for `:nth-child()`..instead go for `:last-child`

```
div.entry-content :last-child {
    background-color: red;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MU6rE/1/)

Comment: Trying that in jsfiddle and not seeing anything change when I run it I am afraid.

Comment: @fakeguybrushthreepwood : edited answer...please see now!! :)

Comment: There are elements below in my actual code, but for this example, this code works, and it definitely might help certain people looking for an answer to a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to point class name after the section pseudo selection.

```
.vc_section_wrapper:nth-child(9) .bg-layer{  
background-color: red;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uCArIko/2/)**